# Can I use an <asp:SessionParameter Direction="Output"/> to *set* a variable?

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, sqldatasource

If I have a SqlDataSource with

```
InsertCommand="INSERT [Applications] ([UserID]) VALUES (@UserID);SELECT @ApplicationID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
```

Can I use a SessionParameter to store the returned value?

```
<asp:SessionParameter SessionField="__ApplicationID" Name="ApplicationID" Type="int32" Direction="Output" DefaultValue="-1" />
```